# ARC converter not removing all calls to release

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've ran the ARC converter multiple files. However, I doesn't remove calls to release in dealloc of my ViewController. Calls like the one below would remain after conversion.

```
- (void)dealloc{
    [myObject release];
}
```

What is the reason that these are not removed?

(also autorelease still remains in the code, and the compiler doesn't complain about it, while it complains on calls to retain)

Comment: Do you have some files that aren't using ARC. I.e. they have the option -fno-objc-arc set in the Compile Sources section?

Comment: Yes, like the ASI files.

Answer (score 0):

If that's not a typo and you pasted verbatim, then it could be because the search and replace pattern didn't account for `blah release]`, only `[blah release]`